# How do I refresh a wordpress shortcode that is a POST API Call to return an image running Elementor

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I have a shortcode that uses WPGetAPI to return a base 64 image from an API via a Post command.  That part is working.  I am trying to create a code snippet to refresh just the image on my page.  The API produced images every 5 seconds so I want to refresh my shortcode widget in Elementor on the page only and not the entire page.  I've tried the following and it will return the image but I cannot figure out how to get the API call to automatically refresh every 5 seconds to get the new image.  Thanks.

The code below is what I have in a snippet and use that to be a shortcode.  Open to other options.  Thanks!

```
<script>
var $image = <?php 
$camapi = wpgetapi_endpoint( 'levelcon2',     'test_camera_php',array('debug' => false) );
echo "<img src=",$camapi['0']['rawImage'],">"
 ?> ;
    var i = 0;
    var renew = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("Image").href = $image[i]; 
        $('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #time');

    },5000);
</script>

<div class="cam_image">
<div id ="refresh">
    <div id="time">
    <?php echo $camapi['0']['rawImage']; ?>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are creating output in the form `var $image = <img src="...">` there, not sure what you think you are accessing with `$image[i]` then afterwards? Plus, reloading the whole current page each time, only to then extract a tiny portion of it to update the currently shown document, is not a very performant approach.